# .htaccess changes to convert query string to directory format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I'm trying to convert my query string urls to a directory structure for SEO purposes. And I have been getting to the point where im trying to say the same logic in many semantical ways in the .htaccess file to see if I can get a result. Here is what I'm looking to do.

The request is:
**mywebsite.com/test/antitrust/somelongfilename/**

Then modified to request:
**mywebsite.com/test/antitrust/?id=news&post=news/somelongfilename.html**

So that when people click on my SEO friendly links they get changed to the ugly ones to which my php code can read. "somelongfilename.html" is not to be shown by itself, its just content thats pushed to a content area of a php file.

FYI, post=news/somelongfilename.html is actually the directory/file to goto from the antitrust directory, so its located /test/antitrust/news. Its been working fine even though its probably not a good idea to put / in a query string.

The .htaccess is in the subdirectory /antitrust, as I don't want to touch the root directory .htaccess as its servicing many websites that I dont want to affect since im not a .htaccess expert.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} news
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.php/?id=news&post=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also tried many variations of this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news$
RewriteRule \/(.+?)\/?   ^?id=news&post=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ?id=(.+?)&post=(.+?) http://mywebsite.com/test/crush/antitrust/$1/$2/ [QSA,R]
```

Any ideas on what part im doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteBase /test/antitrust/

# not sure why you need this, it's not part of your question
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} news

# conditions to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?id=news&post=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, it does not work and generates a 404 for my SEO link(fake link), so no conversation happens. As for RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} news you are right I never asked about that. That is there just to only execute this code for any request containing the word news. Its not really necessary.

Comment: I played around with the RewriteBase to /test/crush/antitust it worked. Thank you so much! So the lessoned learned here is to rewrite the base to the subdirectory your calling the php code from.